# Maintaining/Sharing session between virtual folders

Tags: session-state, cookies

I am a bit confused here.

Under the same Sitecore 8.1 instance, I have two web sites set as two virtual folders (`www.site.com` and `www.site.com/customers`) under the same app pool.
This is a temporary setup; at term the two sites will be merged into one but for various reasons (including $) this can be done now. So a phased approach is needed to integrate the two properties.

All my questions relate to, how could i share the user session between the two sites, namely:

1. Can I share cookies between the two sites (it seems it is not by default;
   for example language preferences seem to be lost between the sites)?
2. How can I recognize the xDB contact between these two sites?
3. Furthermore, I would like to replace the current
   login page in `www.site.com` with a new one in `www.site.com/customers`.
   How can I enable the web session transfer/sharing between the two
   sites (web SSO, custom cookie as I have seen in this post
   [Share Session across Sitecore subsites](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6461/share-session-across-sitecore-subsites)
   but it may impact 2)?

Thanks for your help!